# how to grab part of a url string with php

Tags: php

I am using a filemangement system and to protect the url. Manipulation of the url string is not allowed and leads to killing the page.
I want to make an exception for that when I delete files.

When deleting files, the url string always looks like this:

```
example.com/sfm?delete=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1
```

or

```
example.com/sfm?delete=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/file.jpg
```

or

```
example.com/sfm?delete=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/file.jpg
```

So the minimum of the string contains always:

```
example.com/sfm?delete=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

( the hash is a md5 hash of a userid)

So how can I grab that minimum url string?

Comment: **1.** Is the hash always the same size? **2.** Does `uploads/sfm/` always come?

Comment: yes the hash has always the same number of characters  and also uploads/sfm is always in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `implode`, `array_slice`, `explode`.

Explode will extract the string to array, array slice cut the array upto 4th item, and implode will grab the array items to a new string.

```
$str = 'example.com/sfm?delete=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1 ';

echo $output = implode('/', array_slice(explode("/", $str), 0, 4)); //example.com/sfm?delete=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

Comment: What does `array_slice` do here?

Comment: `array_slice` takes the selected parts of an array. here takes the index from 0 to 4.

Comment: Already you are limiting the `explode` to `4` right? I mean, I just noticed. You can actually limit it to `4` using `explode("/", $str, 4)`.

Comment: may be, but i did it this way. i will try that later.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [`explode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Even if the hash is not of the same size, if you follow the same structure, I would just do this:

```
$delete = explode("/", $_GET["delete"]);
print_r($delete);
```

Outputs to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => uploads
    [1] => sfm
    [2] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
    [3] => folder1
)
```

The `$delete[2]` will give me the hash. I guess this would be the best way, even if the URL changes.